# "mke2fs -r fs-revision-level" - how is this used?

Tags: filesystems, options

`mke2fs -r` offers

> Set the filesystem revision for the new filesystem.  Note that 1.2 kernels only support revision  0  filesystems.  The default is to create revision 1 filesystems.

Trying to look up what was meant by that I found loads of screenshots etc. of  `dumpe2fs`containing the line

> Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)

### Question:

*What does that mean? What does the option actually do and what is meant with this output?*

Where is documented what a value of zero would mean, what *dynamic* actually means; and is there a value of two also?

I could live with »*keep untouched as you won't ever need to change it*« – but as there is an option for that and no note about backward compatibility, this makes me wonder…

Comment: I'm about stumped. I'm thinking it has something to do with ext2 vs. 3, 4.

Comment: @slm First: Wow ;) This is also my guess - but then, it would be a quite non-elegant way defining what version of `ext` should be used. But part with `kernel 1.2` hints into that too…

Comment: There is always the source Luke - http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/mke2fs.c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to really only hinge on what version of the Linux Kernel you're pairing with the filesystem you're attempting to `mke2fs` and also later use with the resulting ext2,3,4 filesystem.

```
fs_param.s_rev_level = 1;  /* Create revision 1 filesystems now */

if (is_before_linux_ver(2, 2))
    fs_param.s_rev_level = 0;
```

Here it's defaulting to 1 unless the kernel's version is below version 2.2. The man page from freeBSD has a little more info on this:

```
-O feature[,...]
      Create filesystem  with  given  features  (filesystem  options).
      Currently,  the sparse_super and filetype features are turned on
      by default unless mke2fs is run on a system with a pre-2.2 Linux
      kernel.  Filesystems that may need to mounted on pre-2.2 kernels
      should be created with -O none (or -r 0 for 1.2  kernels)  which
      will  disable  these features, even if mke2fs is run on a system
      which can support them.
```

So I'm imagining that there are some features that must be lacking in the older kernels (1.2, 2.2, etc.) and this switch is here so that if you need to create a filesystem that will later be mounted on one of these older systems, that you'll be able to create it on the systems with the newer kernels.

There is also additional info in the [release notes for e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/e2fsprogs-release.html) (the package which comprises mke2fs).

*excerpts*

> ***ref#1:*** [E2fsprogs 1.41.1 (September 1, 2008)] Mke2fs will correctly enforce the prohibition against features (specifically read-only features) in revision 0 filesystems. (Thanks to Benno Schulenberg for noticing this problem.)
>
> ***ref#2:*** [E2fsprogs 1.20 (May 20, 2001)] E2fsck will now bump the filesystem revision number from zero to one if any of the compatibility bits are set.
>
> ***ref#3:*** [E2fsprogs 1.15 (July 18, 1999)] Mke2fs now creates revision 1 filesystems by default, and with the sparse superblock feature enabled. The sparse superblock feature is not understood by Linux 2.0 kernels, so they will report errors when mounting the filesystem. This can be worked around by using the mount options "check=none".
>
> ***ref#4:*** [E2fsprogs 1.10 (April 24, 1997)] Mke2fs once again defaults to creating revision #0 filesystems, since people were complaining about breaking compatibility with 1.2 kernels. Warning messages were added to the mke2fs and tune2fs man pages that the sparse superblock option isn't supported by most kernels yet (1.2 and 2.0 both don't support parse superblocks.)
>
> ***ref#5:*** [E2fsprogs 1.08 (April 10, 1997)] Dumpe2fs now prints more information; its now prints the the filesystem revision number, the filesystem sparse_super feature (if present), the block ranges for each block group, and the offset from the beginning of the block group.
>
> ***ref#6:*** [E2fsprogs 1.03 (March 27, 1996)] Support (in-development) filesystem format revision which supports (among other things) dynamically sized inodes.

These comments would seem to address all your questions!