# When we run tune2fs -l /dev/xvdf1. We will get options like "filesystem revision #: 1 (Dynamic)" What does it mean?

Tags: linux, filesystems

When we run tune2fs -l /dev/xvdf1. We will get options like "filesystem revision #: 1 (Dynamic)" What does it mean ?

Comment: A dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114234/mke2fs-r-fs-revision-level-how-is-this-used

Answer (score 2):

“#1 (dynamic)” refers to the revision of the ext2 file system; version 1 [supports dynamic inode sizes](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/lib/ext2fs/ext2_fs.h#n781). This has been in use since kernel 2.2.

See ["mke2fs -r fs-revision-level" - how is this used?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114234/86440) for some of the relevant history.